# Extracting required indices from an array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

y = np.array([[2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0],
             [2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0]])

maximas = signal.argrelmax(y, axis=1)

print maximas

(array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([3, 6, 3, 6], dtype=int64))
```

The maximas produced the index of tuples: (0,3) and (0,6) are for row one [2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0]; and (1,6) and (1,6) are for another row [2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0].

The following prints all the results, but I want to extract only the first maxima of both rows, i.e., [3,3] using the tuples. So, the tuples I need are (0,3) and (1,3).

How can I extract them from the array of tuples, i.e., 'maximas'?

```
>>> print y[kk]
[3 1 3 1]
```

Comment: Are you open to a pure Python solution?

Comment: `y[maximas]` produces `[3 1 3 1]`.  But what you want is `y[(0,1),(3,3)]` producing `[3,3]`, right?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, exactly it is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the tuple `maximas`, here's one possible NumPy way:

```
>>> a = np.column_stack(maximas)
>>> a[np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True)[1]]
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

This stacks the coordinate lists returned by `signal.argrelmax` into an array `a`. The `return_index` parameter of `np.unique` is used to find the first index of each row number. We can then retrieve the relevant rows from `a` using these first indexes.

This returns an array, but you could turn it into a list of lists with `tolist()`.

To return the first column index of the maximum in each row, you just need to take the indices returned by `np.unique` from `maximas[0]` and use them to index `maximas[1]`. In one line, it's this:

```
>>> maximas[1][np.unique(maximas[0], return_index=True)[1]]
array([3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

To retrieve the corresponding values from each row of `y`, you can use `np.choose`:

```
>>> cols = maximas[1][np.unique(maximas[0], return_index=True)[1]]
>>> np.choose(cols, y.T)
array([3, 3])
```

Comment: I want to return back  [3,3] as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a pure Python approach will be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)(group on the row's index) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [max(g, key=lambda x: y[x])
                             for k, g in groupby(zip(*maximas), itemgetter(0))]
[(0, 3), (1, 3)]
```